# Cannot read file within jar file

Tags: java, docker, gradle, spring-boot

I developped an application using spring-boot, I need to read a csv file that contain emails.

this is a snippet how I do:

```
public Set<String> readFile() {
        Set<String> setOfEmails = new HashSet<String>();

        try {
            ClassPathResource cl = new ClassPathResource("myFile.csv");
            File file = cl.getFile();
            Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(file.getPath()));
            setOfEmails = stream.collect(Collectors.toSet());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("file error " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return setOfEmails;
    }
```

It works when I execute the application using eclipse: run As --> spring-boot app

But when I put the jar into a container docker the method readFile() return an empty set.

I use gradle for build the application

Would you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) for `ClassPathResource` state:

> Supports resolution as `java.io.File` if the class path resource resides in the file system, **but not for resources in a JAR**. Always supports resolution as URL.

So when the resource (the CSV file) is in a JAR file, `getFile()` is going to fail.

The solution is to use `getURL()` instead, then open the URL as an input stream, etcetera.  Something like this:

```
public Set<String> readFile() {
    Set<String> setOfEmails = new HashSet<String>();

    ClassPathResource cl = new ClassPathResource("myFile.csv");
    URL url = cl.getURL();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                             new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))) {

        Stream<String> stream = br.lines();
        setOfEmails = stream.collect(Collectors.toSet());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("file error " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return setOfEmails;
}
```

If it still fails check that you are using the correct resource path.

Answer (score 2):

I do not work with Spring, but I found the Javadoc of [ClassPathResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) that states:

> Supports resolution as java.io.File if the class path resource resides in the file system, but not for resources in a JAR. Always supports resolution as URL.

try with `getURL()` instead of `getFile()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://jd.benow.ca/ Jd GUI drop your jar file there and

1. check is the file is there in the jar
2. If Yes then see the path/folder structure where it is placed.
3. If Yes folder exists Access the File using `"/<path>/myFile.csv"`